# dev_server.py : first request when change code alway has a status of 200 and an empty body

Tags: google-app-engine, tornado

I use this in app.yaml

```
- url: /.*
  script: server.application
```

when use dev server

dev_appserver.py --use_sqlite -a 0.0.0.0 -p 8842 /home/bitcoin/42btc

the first time  , is a empty page
the second time , all things are right

I use tornado

```
application = tornado.wsgi.WSGIApplication(
   [
            (r"/(.*)", ViewIndex),
        ],
)
```

when you change code , first requests will print the response in shell , and has a status of 200 and an empty body

```
INFO     2013-03-04 02:26:57,679 dev_appserver_multiprocess.py:658] Admin console is available at: http://0.0.0.0:8942/_ah/admin
INFO     2013-03-04 02:26:58,487 py_zipimport.py:148] zipimporter('/home/bitcoin/42btc/misc/virtualenv.zip', '')
Status: 200
Content-Length: 4792
Etag: "17302e0828d268f8d65efab7c1edb483d0ffa61d"
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Server: TornadoServer/2.4.1
Set-Cookie: _xsrf=cf8c38780922411a859f197e686910a4; Path=/

<!DOCTYPE html><meta charset="utf-8"><script src="/js/init.js"></script><link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/init.css" type="text/css"><title>42btc.com</title><body>

...
```

the second request is ok ....

Answer (score 0):

It looks like stdout may not be getting redirected properly on the first page load.

I don't see this with my version of dev_appserver.  It may be tornado or some other library that you're using.